# Access Head and Tail of List stored in a variable as input to further predicate (Prolog)

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, element

So, I have a simple list. Let's say:

```
L([a,b,c]).
```

I want to access the Head and Tail (H|T) so I can recursively use the elements as input for other predicates. Basically

```
somePredicate(a),
someOtherPredicate(T).
```

until the list is empty. How can I do that?

I generated the list using:

```
range(0,L) :-    
    L = [].
range(1,L) :- 
    L = [].
range(M,L) :-
    NewM is M - 1,
    numlist(1, NewM, L).
```

Comment: Just trying to earn a living

Comment: What you have there is not a list. This is a list: `[a,b,c]`. If you have a list inside a variable, you can split it into head and tail like this: `L = [a,b,c], L = [H|T]`

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
 pre([H|T]):-
        writeln(H),
        writeln(T),
        pre(T).

?-pre([a,b,c]).
OUTPUT:
a
[b, c]
b
[c]
c
[]
```

If you want to use the values with another predicate:

```
pre([H|T]):-
            writeln(H),
            pre1(T),
            pre(T).

pre1([H|T]):-
 writeln([H|T]).

?-pre([a,b,c]).
OUTPUT:
a
[b, c]
b
[c]
c
[]
```